# Permissions issue using node-archiver

Tags: node.js, node-archiver

When I use archiverjs I cannot open the resulting zip file:

```
var archive = archiver('zip');
  var output = fs.createWriteStream(projectName + '.zip');
archive.pipe(output);

  archive.on('error', function(err) {
    throw err;
  });
  output.on('close', function() { 
    console.log('Package complete!');
  });
  archive.bulk([
    {expand: true, cwd: projectPath, src:['**/*'], data: {mode: 0755}}
  ]).finalize();
```

The zip file gets created but I dont have permissions to open it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a check: is the issue that you cannot open the zip file itself, or that you don't have the right permissions on the files coming from the zip once you've extracted them?

Comment: I cannot open the zipfile itself, meaning i cannot extract. I'm assume the files themselves are accessible, since I can open then pre zip.

Comment: Are you sure the file is being written to `projectPath/`. I would expect the write stream to get something like `path.join(projectPath, projectName + '.zip')`

Comment: Yes, the zip file is being written. I just cannot extract the files.

Comment: DOH, just noticed this. Being that you are using streams, you need to make sure the bulk command happens _after_ the output stream and anything else piped onto the archive stream is done.

Comment: I ran your code successfully without change in my machine, maybe its not the posted code that does this, it might be something is interrupting zipping operation, other code maybe